# jQuery select case inside set val function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assume there is a way to make this code more concise but I am not sure how in jQuery:

```
 $('#originTypeToggle').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) { $('#OriginType').val('1') } 
           else { $('#OriginType').val('2') }
        });
```

logically, what I am looking for is:

`$('#OriginType').val() = $(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '2'`

Basically to reduce the redundancy of `$('#OriginType').val('1')` and `$('#OriginType').val('2')`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#OriginType').val($(this).is(':checked') ? "1":"2");
```

Or

```
$('#OriginType').val($(this).prop('checked') ? "1":"2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want:

```
$('#OriginType').val( $(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '2' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#OriginType').val(function(){
    return $('#OriginTypeToggle').prop('checked') ? 1 : 2;
});
```